# How to get enabled entry with GraphQL, enabledForSite has been deprecated?

Tags: graphql

Based on the docs https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/graphql.html#the-entries-query `enabledForSite` can be used for entries. This works for me to get the enabled entries, however I get a deprecation error in Utilities > Deprecation Warnings:

> The enabledForSite element query param has been deprecated.
> status() should be used instead.

But when using `status: "live"`

The query does not work and I get the following error back:

> Unknown argument "status" on field "entries" of type "Query"

Which makes sense as I cannot find it in the docs. It seems to me like `enabledForSite` is what I am looking for and cannot understand why it is giving this warning.

Answer (score 2):

#### Info

I found this info in a GitHub comment by Brandon Kelly: [commented on 30 Jun 2020](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6273#issuecomment-652042120)

---

The `enabledForSite` param is now deprecated and set to `false` by default (as in “don’t worry about it”).

It is now solely the `status` param’s responsibility to worry about elements’ site statuses.

- `enabled` will give you elements that are enabled both globally and for the current site.
- `disabled` will give you elements that are disabled either globally or for the current site (or both).

---

#### Solution

Use `status: "enabled"` instead of `enabledForSite: true`.